# Windows workflow for large scale application

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Has anyone used windows workflow foundation for a large-scale program? We have about 200k new records faily with about a 3-week processing window. So about 5milliok active workflows at once. Has anyone done something like this? I'm hesitant to try it because it seems that Microsoft gave up on WWF.